# Dictionary web-scraper doesn't return example sentences

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want to scrape example usage sentences from [this site](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/creep").

Here is the HTML source of the page:

```
<vcom:examples lang="en" word="creep" count="4" filter="0" class="vcom_examples">

<div class="exampleBrowser hasNext">

<div class="domains">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" title="All Sources" class="selected">All Sources</a><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Fiction" data-code="F">Fiction</a><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Arts / Culture" data-code="A">Arts / Culture</a><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="News" data-code="N">News</a><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Business" data-code="B">Business</a><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Sports" data-code="S">Sports</a><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Science / Med" data-code="M">Science / Med</a><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Technology" data-code="T">Technology</a></div>

<div class="container" style="height: auto;">
<div class="results" style="left: 0px;">

<ul>
<li><div class="sentence">
If you believe their campaigns, it’s the choice between a <strong>creep</strong> and a crook.</div>
<a target="_blank" class="source" href="https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2016/nov/22/journalists-media-election-2016-donald-trump">
<span class="corpus">The Guardian</span>
<span class="date">Nov 22, 2016</span></a>
</li>

<li>
<div class="sentence">
From stingrays to spy planes, we are seeing the consequences of powerful surveillance technology <strong>creeping</strong> into local law enforcement without adequate limits.
</div>
<a target="_blank" class="source" href="http://www.slate.com/articles/technology/future_tense/2016/11/should_police_bodycams_come_with_facial_recognition_software.html">
<span class="corpus">Slate</span>
<span class="date">Nov 22, 2016</span></a>
</li>

</ul></div></div>

<div class="buttons"><a class="prev ss-navigateleft" title="prev">Prev</a><a class="next ss-navigateright right" title="next">Next</a></div></div></vcom:examples>
```

and here is my Python code:

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request

sauce = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/creep').read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce,'lxml')

for examples in soup.find_all('p',class_ = 'sentence'):
    print(examples.text)
```

It was successful in scraping the meaning of words in the same way as above.
However, when I tried to scrape the example sentences in that way, it returned nothing.

Why isn't it returning the example sentences?

Comment: Sentences are inside `div` tags, why do you have `soup.find_all('p',class_ = 'sentence')` ?

Comment: oh- sorry. I copied wrong code. my miss. 
I did it with `div` . but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get that sentences with `beautifulsoup4` because examples are loaded later from json. In html response that section looks like this:

```
<vcom:examples lang="en" word="creep" count="4" filter="0" ></vcom:examples>
```

And is filled later by code from `https://cdn.vocab.com/js/module-esekdz.js`.

Instead of parsing whole html body you can use this minimal snippet to get example sentences directly from json, just choose a word, domain and max results:

```
import requests

search_word = 'creep'
# "Fiction", "Arts / Culture", "News", "Business", "Sports", "Science / Med", "Technology"
domains = [None, "F", "A", "N", "B", "S", "M", "T"]

link = "https://corpus.vocabulary.com/api/1.0/examples.json"

response = requests.get(link, params={'query': search_word, 'domain': domains[0], 'maxResults': 24})

if response.ok:
    for example in response.json()['result']['sentences']:
        print(example['sentence'])
```

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trials with `urllib.request.urlopen` (or `requests.get`) and `bs4`, I also failed to get the `sentence` class. It seems that neither of the methods can fetch the whole contents as can be seen from the web page. In this case, I'm afraid you will have to use some other packages instead, such as `selenium.webdriver`. The code could be as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_driver_path = 'your_working_directory\\chromedriver.exe'
mydriver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver_path)

mydriver.get('https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/creep')
sentences = mydriver.find_elements_by_class_name('sentence')

for sentence in sentences:
    print(sentence.text)
```

Here is a [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bhYulVzYRng), which is very clear and brief, about how to use **"Selenium/ChromeDriver"** to do web scraping.